# Exchange 2013 New Profile Initial Update Slow, ping to server 300ms, updating at 1.5GB per day

Tags: exchange-2013, rackspace, outlook-anywhere, outlook-2013

I am using a well known Exchange 2013 provider and having issues recreating a profile and the initial sync download which has 15GB of mail which is taking weeks to update - during the intial sync/update new emails do not update instantly.

Once synced Outlook and the service in general (including OWA) works fine.

Basically at the DC the provider says it is fine. At the user end, the update time is not acceptable given they have a connection of 75Mbps (tested via speedtest.net), but it is taking weeks to update.

I can see the Exchange OST grows by around 250MB per day, I presume this is expanded out in blocks?

Given the provider would be testing from their machine and have very low latency to the DC (~10ms) verses that of the user to DC (~300ms as per pic below) does Exchange 2013 sync every single email (and thus suffer from latency) or does it do it in bulk (so latency doesn't affect it)?

This is the only thing that i can think why it would be slow from outside verses the DC who test locally.

I have built up a test VM on my lab server and finding after being up for 2.5 hours it has only downloaded 190MB in the OST... this equates to ~1.5GB per day! I have a 20Mbps connection, no packet loss between myself and server.

Anything else I should check for other than corrupt PST/OST, PSTs on network shares, Office Service Packs etc?

Rackspace just say its the ISP (despite me trying from different systems/networks) so no other option than to consider other providers - Has anyone tried Office 365, do they have geographically distributed servers which one can choose from?

[image: status]

Comment: It's a remote server that host the user mailbox ? If yes, OWA work as expected ? I ask as it can be a simple setting like shown there; https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2733062

Comment: What do you mean `update`? Do you mean syncing the OST file? Also, the fact that the user has a 75Mbps connection doesn't mean that the entire path from the user to the server has that bandwidth. Furthermore, 300ms is horrible latency.

Comment: Yes OWA works fine, this is just during the initial update (initial sync) after a profile has been recreated. Once synced Outlook runs fine and receives mail instantly